# Yii Appointment Management system

Tags: php, yii, content-management-system, appointment

I am working on a medical Web App in Yii have to design Appointment management. I already installed Yii User management system, but that does not give what I want. I want to manage the appointments by getting the time slots from the tables and few more options like sms code verification, email verification, users' location finder, If anyone had come across these needs and done for your App may give an idea, which would be the best for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii has a lot of [extensions available](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/). You won't find an exact result for your requirements, but it is possible to add multiple extensions. For example, there is the [efullcalendar](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/efullcalendar/) extension, several [sms extensions](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=sms) and several [geolocation](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=geolocation) extensions, handy for a location finder.

Comment: I have already installed efullCalender, when I click on any date a popup window opens, there I couldn't see the full window it is partially hidden. any idea to make it visible